# run time of nested while loop inside for loop

Tags: algorithms

I'm here to clarify my understanding of the run times of these 2 algorithms:

```
Algorithm1(n):
For i = 1 to n
    j = 1
    while i+j < n
        j = j+1
```

and

```
Algorithm2(n):
For i = 1 to n
    j = 1
    while i*j < n
        j = j+1
```

The first algorithm I believe is `O(n)` because the inner loop is bounded by `n`, and the `while` condition is incremented linearly as `i` is incremented by the outer for loop.  Otherwise, I would say `O(n^2)` if I'm wrong.

The second algorithm I believe is `O(log(n^2))` because, as `i` increases, the amount of iterations will decrease in the `while` loop which is controlled by the outer for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is O(...) and how do I calculate it?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132331/what-is-o-and-how-do-i-calculate-it)

Comment: you while loops iterate over j, starting with j=1 and incrementing it by 1 in each step. So why not use a for loop instead of the wihhile loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first algorithm is O(n^2), as the outer loop executes n times, and on average the inner loop executes n/2 times; we discard the constant factor as we only care about asymptotic behavior.

Your second algorithm is I believe O(n log n): the outer loop again executes n times, so there must be a factor of n in the answer, and I believe the inner loop executes log n times on average.

Note that your suggested answer of O(log (n^2)) is not a valid answer in any case: log (n^2) = 2 log n, so O(log (n^2)) should be simplified to O(log n).